Why is the general unit for energy (in terms of energy bills) $\rm kWh$?
Why is the unit for energy (in terms of energy bills) expressed as $$\text{time} \cdot \frac{\text{energy}}{\text{time}}$$ rather than just energy?
Wouldn't it be better to express it in megajoules (MJ) rather than kWh?

Because it is easier to determine energy use of a 100W lightbulb for an hour…

Why fix what ain't broke? Consumers are used to being billed in kWh and regulations are written in terms of kWh. Hundreds of millions of meters are deployed at customer premises reading in kWh.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.

A note. Megajoules would be useful in the same way if we used kiloseconds (ks) to tell time instead of hours (h). Why we don't? Most likely, because rebuilding every clock in the world is understood as a lot of expense for very little gain.

@The_Sympathizer That makes sense, thanks!

It is a practical (reasonably sized) unit.
If you have a $2\,\rm kW$ electric fire and run it for 5 hours you use $2\times 5 = 10 \,\rm kWh$ of electricity.
Knowing the price per $\rm kWh$ you can easily work out the cost.
Imagine doing this is seconds (having converted from hours) and millions of joules and then the price given per million? joules.

I believe it may be because many household appliances are given power ratings in terms of watts. For example, your average microwave will run of 800W (0.8kW). If you leave your microwave running for 10 hours, you will increase your energy bill by 8kWh. This is the sort of thought process makes it easier for people to understand their energy consumption.
